# Xamarin, is there an easier way to get an Entry converted to float and back and forth?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

How do I get convert Entry to float or numerical so I can add digits together.

I tried converting Entry to float by float.parse.  and if i need float to string it's .Tostring();  but the float.parse is throwing some exception.

```
        //input string
        entry1 = n1.Text;
        //convert
        float floatn1 = float.Parse(entry1);

        //show entered
        //n1Label.Text = entry1;

        entry2 = n2.Text;
        float floatn2 = float.Parse(entry2);

        float sum = floatn1 + floatn2;
        string s = sum.ToString();

        nsumLabel.Text = s;
```

System.format exception error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The exception is being thrown because the `entry1` text is not in the correct format for a float.

Use `float.TryParse` to check:

```
//input string
entry1 = n1.Text;

if(!float.TryParse(entry1, out float floatn1)) {
    // incorrect format
    // tell the user to input a decimal number in a correct format
    return;
}
// correct format, continue
```

`float.TryParse` returns `false` if the value in `entry1` cannot be converted into a float (usually because of an incorrect format). If the format is correct, the float value is stored in the `out` parameter and you can use it.

Comment: format was a string from the placeholder. adjusted it and now it's numerical.